# How spring detects bean defined in dependencies in other packages which are not defined in component scan base package

Tags: java, spring, autowired

How spring detects beans defined in spring dependency jars. Say I have defined base-package for scanning like 'abc.com.*' but in dependency jar DataSource bean is in org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.

Comment: And you really can't read this in the doc?

Comment: is it mentioned somewhere. Can you please share the link

Comment: @user5014677 Can you please share related docs link

Comment: It was a question, i'm pretty sure the doc has the answers to that.

Comment: i did not find any, if you can share any link it would be great